# How to use command link to link to complete action AND then direct user to a URL - JSF (NetBeans)

Tags: java, html, jsf, netbeans

how can I make it so that as well as executing the command in the .java file my command link will also link to a URL once the user clicks OK on the popup box

```
       <h:commandLink
                       onclick = "if (! confirm ('Are you sure?')) return false"
                       value ="VALUE"
                       action ="#{bean.setBooked(item)}"
                       rendered = "#{item.booked >0}">
      </h:commandLink>
```

and the executable code in the java file

```
    public void setBooked (Shop shop)
   { int booking=plot.getBooked();
   plot.setBooked(booking-1);
   updateEntity(plot);
   }
```

I want to make it so that after the user confirms on the OK button they get redirected to an order complete page. How would I go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just return the page name you want to navigate to it via your h:commandLink action.

Answer (score 0):

Just return String from action method, instead of void. It will be handled as standard navigation rule.

```
public String setBooked (Shop shop) {
    int booking=plot.getBooked();
    plot.setBooked(booking-1);
    updateEntity(plot);
    return "orderComplete"
}
```

It is the equivalent of `action="orderComplete"` on `<h:commandLink>`.

Comment: Hi, I get and "unexpected return value" when I add return "orderComplete.xhtml"

Comment: @tyronejavajava No need for .xhtml, try just with "orderComplete" if that's the name of your page. Tke a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/implicit-navigation-in-jsf-2-0/) for JSF 2 navigation rules examples.